# Where is maven-rpm-plugin documentation after codehaus gone

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, rpm

I feel bad for asking this question, but google doesn't help. 
Can anyone tell me where is the documentation for maven-rpm-plugin after the codehaus is gone?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. It seems outside the expectations for a SO question, but where else can we go? Finally a time when a RTFM link would be a great answer. :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maven plugins on Codehaus are being transferred to http://www.mojohaus.org. For the RPM plugin, the link is http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/ but it seems not yet migrated.

For now, its new home appears to be in [this project](https://github.com/mojohaus/rpm-maven-plugin) on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the documentation is unreachable yet? :/

Comment: It seems so. Couldn't find any other place for it.

Comment: I confirm everything above. All Mojo@Codehaus projects have been migrated under the https://github.com/mojohaus organization. That's the right place and the website will be published there soon. Sorry for inconvenience. (I'm a committer on the MojoHaus project, new name for the previously named Mojo@Codehaus one).

Comment: Thanks Baptiste, we are looking forward to see the documentation :)

Comment: In case anyone still bothers, the documentation is up and running.

Comment: Confirmed the site is up now.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the site is not up again, you can see the (almost plain text) documentation source at https://github.com/mojohaus/rpm-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/site/apt

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate the plugin's maven site docs with the following:

```
mvn site:site -Dmaven.test.skip -Dmaven.javadoc.skip
```

The docs are generated in target/site.

(running jdk 1.8.0_25 on linux)

Comment: Had to add  -Dpmd.skip=true  and  comment the line  
  
    <ruleset>http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/mojo-parent-34/src/main/config/pmd/mojo_rules.xml</ruleset>  
  
in the parent pom downloaded to my local repo, too.